# Wann darf bzw. muss man „solch“ nicht beugen?

Tags: adjective, pronoun, inflection

Wiktionary sagt nichts zu dessen ungebeugter Nutzung. Laut [canoo](http://www.canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Demonstr-solch.html) könne es als gewisse ungebeugte Adjektive (z. B. absolut, enorm) als Gradpartikel vor einem Adjektiv stehen. Und da findet man Folgendes:

> ein solch großer Hund
>   mit solch kleinen Summen

Darüber hinaus soll laut dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/solcher) das Demonstrativpronomen *solch* – falls ungebeugt – gehoben wirken.
Ist das alles, was ich zum ungebeugten *solch* wissen soll? D. h., wann darf man *solch* nicht beugen? Wann muss man?

Comment: Ich empfinde *Solch ein großer Hund!* (What a big dog!) nicht als besonders gehoben. Andererseits kam mir im ersten Moment *ein solch großer Hund* allerdings merkwürdig vor.

Comment: @blutorange Weil "ein solch großer Hund" nicht als alleinstehender Satz stehen kann. "Ich habe noch nie einen solch großen Hund gesehen" sollte dir doch wieder natürlich vorkommen.

Comment: In der Umgangssprache ist solch (ungebeugt) sehr selten, weil es weiter verkürzt wird zu so wie zB in So ein Blödsinn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vor *solch* kann ein unbestimmter Artikel stehen. Und das Adjektiv wird dekliniert. Zum Beispiel:

> Das ist eine solch interessante Frage.

Im Plural wird es auch wie ein Adjektiv dekliniert. Zum Beispiel:

> Das sind solch interessante Fragen.

Comment: "Und im Plural wird es auch wie ein Adjektiv dekliniert" im Plural wird `solch` nicht wie ein Adjektiv dekliniert, nur das Adjektiv. Meintest du das?